# Jquery-confirm plugin doesn't submit button type="submit" inside jquery-validation?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using https://jqueryvalidation.org/ plugin and https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm plugin.

I've this code of script:

```
$("#form1").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm',
                content: 'Are you sure?',
                buttons: {
                    ok: {
                        text: "OK",
                        btnClass: 'btn-success',
                        action: function () {           
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        text: "Annulla",
                        action: function () {
                            }
                        }
                }
            });     


        }
);
```

and the form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="var1" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="var2" value="2">
  <input type="text" name="var3" value="3">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="edit" name="action">EDIT</button>
</form>
```

the page itself index.php:

```
if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "edit" ) {
   echo "EDITED";
   exit();
}

var_dump($_POST);
```

The problem is that button submit is not passed!! I don't know why. My var_dump says there are all 3 inputs type="text" but not the button.

I tried removing jquery-confirm and it's ok, all inputs and button type submit are passed:

```
$("#form1").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
);
```

I don't know how to solve. I don't know how to post an example with jsfiddle using $_POST and PHP.

Comment: You already have syntax errors in your JS, please copy and paste your correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because `submit()` does not include the submit button. You'd have to push the value of the button manually.

An example on how this might be done:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$("#form1").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm',
                content: 'Are you sure?',
                buttons: {
                    ok: {
                        text: "OK",
                        btnClass: 'btn-success',
                        action: function () { 
                            let variables = $('#form1').serializeArray();
                            variables.push({name: $('#form1 button').attr('name'), value: $('#form1 button').attr('value')})

                            // Perform custom XHR here ($.ajax) with `variables`

                        }
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        text: "Annulla",
                        action: function () {
                            }
                        }
                }
            });     


        }
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n2gwjvqd/2/

PS: it makes sense to cache jquery selectors so

`variables.push({name: $('#form1 button').attr('name'), value: $('#form1 button').attr('value')})`

might become

```
let button = $('#form1 button');
variables.push({name: button.attr('name'), value: button.attr('value')})
```